# achart engine annotation raising exception errors

Tags: android, annotations, achartengine

I am trying to develop an app that will display a graph.On the y-axis there will be data and on the x-axis months(e.g jan,feb,march,april ...).As far as i know am trying to use annotations to add the months but am having errors.I cant seem to find a good enough example on how to use annotations.Please help.Heres is my code.

```
public class LineGraph {
public Intent getIntent(Context context){

    int x[]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int y[]={1,4,9,16,25,36};
    String xaxis[]={"jan","feb","march","april","june","july","august"};

    TimeSeries series=new TimeSeries("line1");

    for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++){
        series.add(x[i],y[i]);
        series.addAnnotation(xaxis[i], x[i], y[i]);

    }

    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset=new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    dataset.addSeries(series);

    XYSeriesRenderer renderer=new XYSeriesRenderer();
    renderer.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.SQUARE);
    renderer.setFillPoints(true);

    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer=new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
    mRenderer.setChartTitle("haha");

    Intent intent = ChartFactory.getLineChartIntent(context,dataset,mRenderer,"Line graph title");
    return intent;
}
  }
```

I am trying to display text lables for the x-axis instead of integer values.A better aproach is also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Annotations are a good choice for displaying random text wherever you need on the graph. In order to display custom labels, you will have to add custom labels:

```
renderer.addXTextLabel(x, text);
```

You will also need to disable the default numerical labels:

```
renderer.setXLabels(0);
```

Comment: Thanks dan for the answer.But how do i add custom labels dynamically?

Comment: The same way you were adding annotations.